# AUC always equal to 1 in CatBoost's cross-validation

Tags: python, cross-validation, catboost

I have been trying to perform cross-validation on CatBoost models. I know almost for certain that all functions that the provided piece of code relies on works correctly, and the parameters and data sets that i run in the cv function appears to be correct. Still the AUC score is always 1 for all data sets.

```
def train_cat(file, cat_feat):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    print("Model Bayesian Optimization")
    params = optimize_catboost(file, cat_feat)
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    
    df = pd.read_csv('./Data/'+file+'.csv')
    for i in cat_feat:
        df[i] = df[i].astype(np.int) 
    
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    
    cv_data = df

    labels =  df['label']

    cat2 = cat_feat

    cv_dataset = Pool(data=cv_data,
                      label=labels,
                      cat_features=cat2)
    params2=list(params[0].values())
    
    params = {'learning_rate' : params2[2], 'reg_lambda' : params2[4], 
              'max_depth' : int(params2[3]), 'colsample_bylevel' : params2[0],
              'iterations':int(params2[1]), 'custom_metric':'AUC',
              'thread_count':4, 'task_type':'CPU','verbose':False,
              "loss_function": "Logloss"}

    auc = cv(cv_dataset,
                params,
                fold_count=10, 
                plot="True")
    
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print(f'Model Training Time: {stop - start} s')  
    time = stop - start
    print("Model Train and Test AUC Report")
    
    return auc, time, params
```

Comment: It looks like you have included the class labels in the feature matrix as `cv_data` is set equal to the full data frame `df`, including the `label` column.

Answer (score 1):

You **must** remove the `label` feature from you features dataframe. You're getting an AUC of 1 because the target is among the features, therefore a linear correlation.

```py
cv_data = df.drop(columns=['label'], axis=1)
```